# Is There an Already Made Alphabet List In Python?

Tags: python

I need to create random word/names with `random.choice(alphabet)` for many of my games in repl,
but it is a pain to type it out, and make uppercase versions, consonants/vowels only, etc.

Is there a built-in or importable way to get a pre-made one in python?

Comment: `import string` and then `string.ascii_lowercase` or `string.ascii_uppercase` for the uppercase version or `string.ascii_letters` for both upper and lowercase.

Comment: Why don't you write a module yourself. It should be simple. And you can re-use it anywhere that you want

Comment: Do you want a certain pattern of letters or can it be literally random?

Comment: I don't know how to write a module. Thanks Chrispresso!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `string` module provides several (English-centric) values:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> string.ascii_uppercase
'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> string.digits
'0123456789'
```

You'll have to create your own vowel/consonant lists, as well as lists for other languages.

Given how short the list of vowels is, vowels and consonants aren't too painful:

```
>>> vowels = set("aeiou")
>>> set(string.ascii_lowercase).difference(vowels)
{'b', 'f', 'v', 'q', 's', 'w', 'y', 'l', 'g', 'j', 'z', 'c', 'h', 'p', 'x', 'd', 'm', 'n', 't', 'k', 'r'}
```

Comment: Note that the `set.difference` method accepts any iterable, so `set(string.ascii_lowercase).difference('aeiou')` will do.