# How to build the variable as an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, string, variables

I need to build a mini program that the user types something in the input and the output will be the alphabet without the letters that the user put in the input. So i wrote this:

```
alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]
text = input("Please enter any text")
for character in text:
    if character in alphabet:
        alphabet.remove(character)
print(alphabet)
```

But now I need to build the variable alphabet as an array, using ascii, without having to assign the letters manually, how do I do it?

Comment: One option is to use [`chr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord): `[chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]`

Comment: `import string; alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alphabet range in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16060899/6045800)

Comment: Or [Is There an Already Made Alphabet List In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58960689/6045800) or even [Python: how to print range a-z?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3190122/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

text = set(input()) # text = input() is also fine
print([c for c in ascii_lowercase if c not in text])
```

Since `text` can be quite long, it's better to convert it into a set before starting using `if c not in text`. This is completely optional though if you don't care about time complexity.

Another option (here you use the fact that each letter can be converted to a character by using `ord`, and consecutive letters map to consecutive numbers):

```
text = set(input()) # text = input() is also fine
print([chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1) if chr(i) not in text])
```

One more option (difference between two sets, followed by a sorting operation):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

text = input()
print(sorted(set(ascii_lowercase) - set(text)))
```